# AsyncIO task doesn't end when the method is essentially finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

I am trying to run a coroutine and wait for its return value with `eventloop.run_until_complete`, but I noticed that `run_until_complete` returns a lot of time after the coroutine is essentially finished (it does return eventually).

Here the snippet of what I tried:

```py
def wait_for_message(timeout_sec):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(_receive_pb_msgs(timeout_sec))
    res = loop.run_until_complete(fut)

    return res

async def _receive_msgs(timeout_sec):
    start_time = time()
    current_time = start_time
    text = None
    async with wsc.connect("URL") as ws:
        while current_time - start_time <= timeout_sec:
            jdata = await ws.recv()
            msg = json.loads(jdata)
            if some_criteria:
                text = msg
                break

            current_time = time()
            await sleep(.1)
    print(f"return: {current_time - start_time}")
    return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = time()
    msg = wait_for_message(10)
    e = time()
    print(f"actual: {e - s})
```

and the output:

```
return: 6.387637138366699
actual: 38.61859059333801
```

As you can see the loop take about 38 seconds to finish even though the function finished after 6 seconds.

Is there anything I am missing here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `break` on `some_criteria` will leave `current_time` outdated (since current iteration won't be taken into account)
2. some `async with` exiting cleanups may happen after you store `current_time` last time

You should definitely place line `current_time = time()` right before printing `return:`. It'll probably fix discrepancy.

Comment: Yes! the cleanups when exiting `async with` did take too long. Thank you.